# Format Date value from database Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a column named `birth_date` in MySQL database with a type of `date`.

[image]

Now, I would like to show it in my view in this format : **May 23, 2008**

I tried:

```
{{ $user->user_information->birth_date->format('m-d-Y') }}
```

it showed:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function format() on string

I also tried

```
{{ date('m-d-Y', $user->user_information->baptism_date) }}
```

it showed:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) A non well formed numeric value encountered

Can anyone assist me with the right formatting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date()` function for this purpose like:

```
date('m-d-Y', strtotime($user->user_information->birth_date));
```

or you can also use `Carbon` for this purpose like:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->user_information->birth_date)->format('m-d-Y')}}
```

**For May 23, 2008**:

```
date('M d, Y', strtotime($user->user_information->birth_date));
```

Working code [snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/536367c4cdd776a022b84a5fd95d1d4b0cb09744)

`date()` format list is available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

`M` - A short textual representation of a month, three letters

Comment: Tried both functions and both produces 05-23-2008. Great. Hoping there is a way to make it May 23, 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->user_information->birth_date)->format('F d, Y') }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The output is 05-23-2008. Is there an alternative to make it May 23, 2008?

Comment: @JustinF Check now

Comment: That is the right format I am looking for. `->format('F d, Y')` nicely done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use date function. try this code:

```
{{ date('F j, Y', strtotime($user->user_information->birth_date)); }}
```